# how to enable/disable monetization for videos uploaded by youtube api

Tags: java, youtube-api

I read from the document [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/model/Video.html) that there's a method `setMonetizationDetails(VideoMonetizationDetails monetizationDetails)`, so here's my code

```
Video videoObjectDefiningMetadata = new Video();

// Set the video to be publicly visible. This is the default
// setting. Other supporting settings are "unlisted" and "private."
VideoStatus status = new VideoStatus();
status.setPrivacyStatus("public");
videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setStatus(status);

//set accesspolicy: allow monetize or not
AccessPolicy accessPolicy = new AccessPolicy();
accessPolicy.setAllowed(false);

VideoMonetizationDetails videoMonetizationDetail = new VideoMonetizationDetails();
videoMonetizationDetail.setAccess(accessPolicy);

videoObjectDefiningMetadata.setMonetizationDetails(videoMonetizationDetail);

/*set snippet*/
YouTube.Videos.Insert videoInsert = youtube.videos()
            .insert("monetizationDetails,snippet,statistics,status,contentDetails", videoObjectDefiningMetadata, mediaContent);
```

it gives an error

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code: 403 : Forbidden
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.common",
    "message" : "Forbidden",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Forbidden"
}
```

Any one know how to use this method? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method is part of the Content ID API, which is limited to premium partners. More info about partnership: https://www.youtube.com/yt/creators/creator-benefits.html
Then you can ask your representative about the API.